# Terraform add dynamique suffix into variable configuration file

Tags: terraform

I have a variable file in the root of my terraform (terraform.auto.tfvars). I would like to declare a prefix variable that I can use in another variable in the same file like below :

```
locations = {
  eastus = { name = "eastus" }
}

resources_group = {
  prod = { name = "PROD-"${var.locations.eastus.name} }
}
```

How to do this with terraform?

Thanks for your help

I have try without success

```
locations = {
  eastus = { name = "eastus" }
}

resources_group = {
  prod = { name = "PROD-"[var.locations.eastus.name] }
}
```

Comment: You cannot assign the values to variable dynamically the way you are trying. What you could do is create a local variable, called e.g., `resource_group` and then use the syntax you are trying inside the variables file.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this directly into the .tfvars, but you can achieve it by doing something like the following:

Define your variables

```
locations = {
  eastus = { name = "eastus" }
}

resources_group_prefix = {
  prod = { name = "PROD" }
}
```

And then, in one of your .tf files (e.g. in `locals.tf`), add:

```
locals {
  resources_group = {
    prod = {
      name = "${var.resources_group_prefix.prod.name}-${var.locations.eastus.name}" }
  }
}
```

Comment: perfect .. thx for your help